# JDBC local MSSQL Server connection string

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, connections

I have installed open source database management tool "dbeaver" and want to use it instead of Sql Server Management Studio. But there is a problem. I searched from the internet but somehow I could not connect to db using dbeaver.

My instance name is: "OMER-HP\OKSQLEXPRESS2014"
I want to connect: "Follower" db
User name: sa
Pwd: Aa123456

Connection String: 
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Follower;instanceName=OMER-HP\OKSQLEXPRESS2014;

Could you help please on this issue

Here is the scrennshot:
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found my answer from dbeaver support forum.

http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=624&p=4261#p4261

First enable TCP/IP for your SQL instance in the SQL Server Configuration Manager tool.

1. Open SSCM and navigate to SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for
   SQLEXPRESS > TCP/IP
2. Enable the TCP/IP protocol in the Properties
   dialog for TCP/IP. (You can also enable it on the right-click menu.)
3. Set the TCP/IP port -- which can only be done in the Properties
   dialog (i.e., can't do it with just a right-click).  On the "IP
   Addresses" tab of that Properties dialog, I used the IPAll settings
   at the bottom. Clear out TCP Dynamic Ports, then set TCP Port to
   1433.

From within DBeaver, you can create either a jDTS or a "Microsoft Driver" connection

To create a jTDS connection in DBeaver

1. Create a new connection, specifying MS SQL Server | jTDS driver
2. Fill out the info on the first (General) tab, complete with User name and Password. I was able to enter my User name as just my Windows user name, not domain\username. But domain\username worked too, and that may be required on some networks. (I'm not sure.)
3. Go to the "Driver properties" tab and re-specify the DOMAIN and the USER as two separate parameters.
   I did not need to re-specify my PASSWORD on the "Driver properties" tab.
   And just to emphasize where to enter this: it's entered on the "Driver properties" tab -- not in the dialog box you get to by clicking the "Edit Driver Settings" button that's on the General tab.
4. Click the "Test Connection..." button to make sure it works, click Next a couple of times, then click Finish.

To create a "Microsoft Driver" connection in DBeaver

1. Create a new connection, specifying MS SQL Server | Microsoft Driver
2. Fill out the info on the first (General) tab, without specifying User name and Password (leave them blank).
3. Go to the Driver properties tab and set integratedSecurity=true.
   And, once again, just to emphasize where to enter this: it's entered on the "Driver properties" tab -- not in the dialog box you get to by clicking the "Edit Driver Settings" button that's on the General tab.
4. Click the "Test Connection..." button to make sure it works, click Next a couple of times, then click Finish.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Just to let a feedback here, I was able to make the connection with the jTDS driver, but couldn't do it with the Microsoft one.

Answer (score 3):

The standard template for a JDBC connection string to SQL Server is

```
jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]
```

[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.110).aspx)

Please make sure that TCP/IP has been enabled for your instance. By default, only Shared Memory is enabled in the Network Configuration of SQL Server Configuration Manager and only the `(local)` connection can be made. I don't believe that JDBC supports that method.